# SMS permission issue resurfaced and play store now rejected my app update

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

So I had the Play Store complaining about one of my apps having the READ_SMS, RECEIVE_SMS permissions. I struggled but was able to solve the issue by uploading an APK without those permissions in the internal channel and promoted it up till it reached the production channel in order to clear the channels from old APKs with those permissions.Everything was fine until I updated my app yesterday and noticed that my app update was rejected! I was surprised that there is still an active apk in the alpha channel requesting those permissions.

Anyway, so I acted quickly and tried to create a new release in the alpha channel with an APK that doesn't include nay of those permissions. But I wasn't able to overcome the declaration form that kept showing up even though it shouldn't, as I was uploading an APK that doesn't include those permissions in any way.

I tried to promote the clean APK without the violating permissions from the internal channel up to the alpha channel, but its the same thing, I am faced with this declaration form.

How can I bypass that declaration form? I mean I am not using those permissions and I clearly believe that I should not fill that form.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because distribution platform policies are not related to programming.

Comment: apologies, where should I post such a thing @Pawel?

Comment: Solved this yet?

Comment: nop, still in an ongoing communication with the playstore support team, once done will document what I did and what they requested

Answer (score 1):

You can add this in your manifest section

[**`tools:node="remove"`**](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge)

> Remove this element from the merged manifest. Although it seems like
>   you should instead just delete this element, using this is necessary
>   when you discover an element in your merged manifest that you don't
>   need, and it was provided by a lower-priority manifest file that's out
>   of your control (such as an imported library).

**Example** - **RECEIVE_SMS**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" tools:node="remove" />
```